# Why is my MVC Website bound to other MVC Website in the same solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two MVC projects in the same solution,

MVCWebsite 1 (main)
MVCWebsite 2 (separate MVC empty project, has assembly reference to MVCWebsite 1)

Initially I had a conflict with the *multiple-types-were-found-that-match-the-controller-named-x* error, so I put in a temp namespace route to fix that but now I get exceptions because, MVCWebsite 2, is somehow kicking off the entire lifecycle of MVCWebsite 1.

I've scoured through my namespaces to check they are all separate, and it looks ok. (event checked Global.ascx)

Am I allowed to reference another MVC application from one MVC application?
What can I do to try and fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any namespace restrictions in route configuration, ASP.NET MVC will look for a controller in all loaded types. Since the other website is referenced in your current website, controller types from that assembly will also be scanned. If both websites have `HomeController` for example, it can't be resolved without a namespace restriction.

Comment: Yes I've since fixed that as mentioned in my question. The routing issue is solved. But for some reason the whole lifecycle from MVCWebsite 1 is being kicked off

Comment: @Baconbeastnz What do you mean by whole lifecycle? Where do you get exceptions exactly? Actions that shouldn't have invoked?

Comment: Think I've found the issue. A call to a static helper in the other project, was implictly kicking off it's type initialiser. My apologies!

Comment: Just a suggestion, can't you move classes that you use in both MVC applications to separate assembly/project? Referencing MVC applications assembly in other project looks like project/code "smell".